# HTTP 300 Multiple Choices on Apache Server

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I allow my Apache server to return 300 Multiple Choices responses? It would have to be done using .htaccess and using a PHP page as the error page.

So far I got this:

```
ErrorDocument 300 "/300.php"
```

The valid URL being http://www.example.com/index.html and the test URL being http://www.example.com/index.php. When I use the test URL, I just get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does index.php exist? Does it return a 300 header?

Comment: No, as far as I understand a 300 status page will return a list of up to 5 valid pages. Check out this status code: http://www.w3.org/standards/agents/authoring.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you like to enable [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: Is mod_negotiation loaded? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html

Comment: Not sure how to tell but I know the server supports it. http://support.godaddy.com/godaddy/apache-multiviews/

Comment: According to this page, it should be already activated. There should be nothing you need to do to get the 300 MultiView pages. Maybe ask your provider why it does not work.

Comment: contacted them and theyre saying i have to proove its them pretty much -.- any other ideas?